# Python, pycharm changes attribute from list to None, why?

Tags: python, pycharm, nonetype, class-attributes

When I'm creating a new class, if one of my attribute is an empty list, pychram suggest to change it to this:

```py
class meet_angle_cond:
    def __init__(self, xy_lat_lon_list=None):
        if xy_lat_lon_list is None:
           xy_lat_lon_list = []
           self.xy_lat_lon_list = xy_lat_lon_list
```

I'm struggling to understand why this is better than:

```py
class meet_angle_cond:
    def __init__(self, xy_lat_lon_list=[]):
           self.xy_lat_lon_list = xy_lat_lon_list
```

It seems to me that this way is more effective and readable.

Comment: It is because of [this](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

Comment: Pycharm is actually doing you a favor by preventing you from getting confusing bugs with mutable default arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Because lists are mutable. Check these snippets.

```
def append_to(element, to=[]):
    to.append(element)
    return to
```

What You Might Have Expected to Happen

```
my_list = append_to(12)
print(my_list)

my_other_list = append_to(42)
print(my_other_list)
```

Expected output,

```
[12]
[42]
```

Actual output,

```
[12]
[12, 42]
```

So pycharm suggests you to use `None` as default argument.